How to speed up the interpolation for this particular example?
I made a script that performs tri-linear interpolation on a set of points using pandas for data handling and Numba for computational efficiency. Currently, it requires $\mathcal{O}(1) \text{ s}$ if considering $10^{5}$ points.
This is the code, assuming some test tabulated data:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import jit

# Define the symbolic function
def custom_function(x, y, z):
    return np.sin(y) * np.cos(3 * y)**(1 + 5 * x) * np.exp(-np.sqrt(z**2 + x**2) * np.cos(3 * y) / 20) / z

# Define the grid ranges
x_range = np.arange(0.5, 5.5, 0.5)
y_range = np.logspace(np.log10(0.0001), np.log10(0.1), int((np.log10(0.1) - np.log10(0.0001)) / 0.1) + 1)
z_range = np.arange(0.5, 101, 5)

# Generate the DataFrame
data = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': [], 'f': []}

for x in x_range:
    for y in y_range:
        for z in z_range:
            data['x'].append(x)
            data['y'].append(y)
            data['z'].append(z)
            data['f'].append(custom_function(x, y, z))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the tri-linear interpolation function using Numba
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def trilinear_interpolation(rand_points, grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, distr):
    results = np.empty(len(rand_points))
    len_y, len_z = grid_y.shape[0], grid_z.shape[0]

    for i in range(len(rand_points)):
        x, y, z = rand_points[i]
        
        idx_x1 = np.searchsorted(grid_x, x) - 1
        idx_x2 = idx_x1 + 1
        idx_y1 = np.searchsorted(grid_y, y) - 1
        idx_y2 = idx_y1 + 1
        idx_z1 = np.searchsorted(grid_z, z) - 1
        idx_z2 = idx_z1 + 1
        
        idx_x1 = max(0, min(idx_x1, len(grid_x) - 2))
        idx_x2 = max(1, min(idx_x2, len(grid_x) - 1))
        idx_y1 = max(0, min(idx_y1, len_y - 2))
        idx_y2 = max(1, min(idx_y2, len_y - 1))
        idx_z1 = max(0, min(idx_z1, len_z - 2))
        idx_z2 = max(1, min(idx_z2, len_z - 1))

        x1, x2 = grid_x[idx_x1], grid_x[idx_x2]
        y1, y2 = grid_y[idx_y1], grid_y[idx_y2]
        z1, z2 = grid_z[idx_z1], grid_z[idx_z2]

        z111 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y1, idx_z1]
        z211 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y1, idx_z1]
        z121 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y2, idx_z1]
        z221 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y2, idx_z1]
        z112 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y1, idx_z2]
        z212 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y1, idx_z2]
        z122 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y2, idx_z2]
        z222 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y2, idx_z2]

        xd = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)
        yd = (y - y1) / (y2 - y1)
        zd = (z - z1) / (z2 - z1)

        c00 = z111 * (1 - xd) + z211 * xd
        c01 = z112 * (1 - xd) + z212 * xd
        c10 = z121 * (1 - xd) + z221 * xd
        c11 = z122 * (1 - xd) + z222 * xd

        c0 = c00 * (1 - yd) + c10 * yd
        c1 = c01 * (1 - yd) + c11 * yd

        result = c0 * (1 - zd) + c1 * zd

        results[i] = np.exp(result)

    return results

# Provided x value
fixed_x = 2.5  # example provided x value

# Random points for which we need to perform tri-linear interpolation
num_rand_points = 100000  # Large number of random points
rand_points = np.column_stack((
    np.full(num_rand_points, fixed_x),
    np.random.uniform(0.0001, 0.1, num_rand_points),
    np.random.uniform(0.5, 101, num_rand_points)
))

# Prepare the grid and distribution values
grid_x = np.unique(df['x'])
grid_y = np.unique(df['y'])
grid_z = np.unique(df['z'])
distr = np.zeros((len(grid_x), len(grid_y), len(grid_z)))

for i in range(len(df)):
    ix = np.searchsorted(grid_x, df['x'].values[i])
    iy = np.searchsorted(grid_y, df['y'].values[i])
    iz = np.searchsorted(grid_z, df['z'].values[i])
    distr[ix, iy, iz] = df['f'].values[i]

# Perform tri-linear interpolation
interpolated_values = trilinear_interpolation(rand_points, grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, distr)

# Display the results
for point, value in zip(rand_points[:10], interpolated_values[:10]):
    print(f"Point {point}: Interpolated value: {value}")

I am wondering if there are any optimization techniques or best practices that I can apply to further speed up this code, especially given that all x-values are fixed. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

In trilinear_interpolation function I would try replacing searchsorted with custom implementation of binary search (like the one here) and add numba decorator to it. Second thing, I would consider using float32 instead of float64.

if you are using trilinear_interpolation function only once, consider caching compiled version. Or adding signature (like here) to speed-up compilation

@dankal444 : I will use it many times for various x parameters defined in-flight.

@dankal444 : but the tabulated data will remain the same.

On my PC, trilinear_interpolation takes only 6 milliseconds. Do you want to optimize it because you want it to run in microseconds? Or is it because you are actually using it with larger inputs?

@ken : sorry, I did not mention that my actual tabulated distribution has much more rows. Also, I will use this function many times.

It seems that there is no need to use searchsorted in this code. For example, for z it can be idx_z1 = int((z - 0.5) // 5). Is this because grid_z is pseudo data? If so, can you describe your actual grid in more detail?

@ken : the actual grid is irregular. It is a combination of several linear and logarithmic grids.

The most obvious thing would be to parallelize the function for i in nb.prange(len(rand_points)): only setting parallel=True is also necessary, but almost always not enough. There should be also a warning...

@max9111 Indeed, there is a big warning about that. On my machine it scale pretty well.

First of all, grid_x, grid_y and grid_z are small so a binary search is not the most efficient way to find a value. A basic linear search is faster for small arrays. Here is an implementation:
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64)', inline='always')
def searchsorted_opt(arr, val):
    i = 0
    while i < arr.size and val > arr[i]:
        i += 1
    return i

When the array is as significantly more items, then you can start at the middle of the array and skip 1 item over N (typically with a small N).
When the array is huge, then a binary search becomes a fast solution. One can build an index to avoid cache misses or used cache-friendly data structures like B-tree. In practice, I do not expect such a data structure to be useful in your case since you operate on a 3D grid so the 3 arrays should certainly always be rather small.
An alternative solution is to build a lookup-table (LUT) based on values in the grid_* arrays. For items following a uniform distribution, you can do something like idx = LUT[int(searchedValue * stride + offset)]. In other cases, you can compute a polynomial correction before the integer conversion so for the LUT access to be uniform and for the LUT to stay small. For smooth functions, you can directly compute the function or a polynomial approximation of it and then truncate the result -- no need for a LUT. But again, this only worth it if the grid_* arrays are significantly bigger.
Moreover, your code does not currently benefit from multiple threads. You need to explicitly use prange instead of range as pointed out by max9111 in comments.
Finally, you can specify a signature so to avoid a possible lazy compilation time, as pointed out by dankal444.
Here is the resulting code:
import numba as nb
@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[:,:,::1])', parallel=True)
def trilinear_interpolation(rand_points, grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, distr):
    results = np.empty(len(rand_points))
    len_y, len_z = grid_y.shape[0], grid_z.shape[0]

    for i in nb.prange(len(rand_points)):
        x, y, z = rand_points[i]

        idx_x1 = searchsorted_opt(grid_x, x) - 1
        idx_x2 = idx_x1 + 1
        idx_y1 = searchsorted_opt(grid_y, y) - 1
        idx_y2 = idx_y1 + 1
        idx_z1 = searchsorted_opt(grid_z, z) - 1
        idx_z2 = idx_z1 + 1

        idx_x1 = max(0, min(idx_x1, len(grid_x) - 2))
        idx_x2 = max(1, min(idx_x2, len(grid_x) - 1))
        idx_y1 = max(0, min(idx_y1, len_y - 2))
        idx_y2 = max(1, min(idx_y2, len_y - 1))
        idx_z1 = max(0, min(idx_z1, len_z - 2))
        idx_z2 = max(1, min(idx_z2, len_z - 1))

        x1, x2 = grid_x[idx_x1], grid_x[idx_x2]
        y1, y2 = grid_y[idx_y1], grid_y[idx_y2]
        z1, z2 = grid_z[idx_z1], grid_z[idx_z2]

        z111 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y1, idx_z1]
        z211 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y1, idx_z1]
        z121 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y2, idx_z1]
        z221 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y2, idx_z1]
        z112 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y1, idx_z2]
        z212 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y1, idx_z2]
        z122 = distr[idx_x1, idx_y2, idx_z2]
        z222 = distr[idx_x2, idx_y2, idx_z2]

        xd = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)
        yd = (y - y1) / (y2 - y1)
        zd = (z - z1) / (z2 - z1)

        c00 = z111 * (1 - xd) + z211 * xd
        c01 = z112 * (1 - xd) + z212 * xd
        c10 = z121 * (1 - xd) + z221 * xd
        c11 = z122 * (1 - xd) + z222 * xd

        c0 = c00 * (1 - yd) + c10 * yd
        c1 = c01 * (1 - yd) + c11 * yd

        result = c0 * (1 - zd) + c1 * zd

        results[i] = np.exp(result)

    return results

Note that np.exp can be computed faster using both the SIMD-friendly library Intel SVML (only for x86-64 CPUs) and multiple threads, by moving np.exp away of the loop and computing it in a second step (while making sure SVML can be using by Numba on the target platform). That being said, the speed up should be small since np.exp only takes a small fraction of the execution time.
The provided code is 6.7 times faster on my i5-9600KF CPU with 6 cores. I do not think this can can be optimized further using Numba on mainstream CPUs (besides using aforementioned methods). At least, it is certainly not possible with the current target input (especially since everything fit in the L3 cache on my machine and distr even fit in the L2 cache).
